# How to properly handle popups (modals) in AngularJS app without bootstrap

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have few popups in my application. One is for displaying "About" and the second one for displaying contact form. What I do currently is I put the whole popup DOM into template and write custom directive like this:

```
angular.module('app').directive('contactForm', function() {

  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    replace: true,
    scope: {},
    templateUrl: 'contactForm.html',
    controller: function($scope) {
      $scope.submitForm = function() {
        ...  
      }
    },
    link: function(scope, el) {
      scope.$on('openContactForm', function() {
        el.show();
      });
    }
  }

});
```

and call such directive somewhere in my index.html

```
<body>
  <about-popup></about-popup>
  <contact-form></contact-form>
  ...
  ...
</body>
```

Somewhere on the page there is controller like this with function bound to button:

```
angular.module('app').controller('SideBarController', function($scope, $rootScope) {
  $scope.openContactForm = function() {
    $rootScope.$broadcast('openContactForm');
  }
});
```

I don't feel that's the best way of handling that, but can't figure out how to do this better. Do you have any ideas, examples?

Comment: You can just use `ng-show` or `ng-hide`.

Answer (score 0):

The last app I did needed a simple modal to display messages and the way I did was with a directive very similar to yours.

The directive appends the template and uses the $rootScope to store a modal object, this object has the attribute show (used by the ng-show in the template) and the toggle function that is called every time I need to show/hide the modal window. Because the object is in the $rootScope you can use it from anywhere.

Here is a simplified version of that directive.

```
app.directive('myModal', ['$rootScope', function ($rootScope) {
    return {
    restric: 'A',
    replace: true,
    template: '<div class="modal" ng-show="modal.show">{{ modal.mainMessage }}<br /><button ng-click="modal.toggle()">Close</button></div>',
    link: function (scope, elm, attrs) {
       $rootScope.modal= {
          mainMessage: '',
          show: false,
          toggle: function (mainMessage) {
             this.mainMessage = mainMessage;
             this.show = !this.show;
          }
       };
     }
  };
}]);
```

Here is a [JSBin](http://jsbin.com/oWuCUNu/1/edit).

This is a good question, I am curious about the answers it will get.